# Adding strings to a list while in a while loop - not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add strings to a variable, and for some reason, the only part that is taking is the "
Services: " part.

Any idea why this might be the case?

```
$lists = "<br />Services: ";

$servicearray = mysql_query("select serv_id from org_serv_xref where org_id='".$orgid."'");

while ($servicearrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servicearray)) {
    $servdescarray = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".$servicearrayrow['serv_id']."'");

    $lists . "<ul>";

while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) {
       $lists . "<li>" . $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'] . "</li>";
      }
      $lists . "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: This has to be the fifth time I've seen this code today.

Comment: To be fair, this is in an entirely different page, just a similar functionality!

Comment: To be fair, you might want to research how to do things a bit before posting questions on SO and wasting everyone's time w/something that could be figured out in less than 30 seconds on Google.

Answer (score 6):

Thats because when you want to concatenate strings, you have to still use the `=` sign, which makes the concat symbol like `.=`

Your code has to look like this:

```
while ($servicearrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servicearray)) 
{
    $servdescarray = mysql_query("select serv_desc from service where serv_id='".$servicearrayrow['serv_id']."'");
    $lists .= "<ul>";

    while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array($servdescarray)) 
    {
        $lists .= "<li>" . $servdescarrayrow['serv_desc'] . "</li>";
    }
    $lists .= "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: To add to this, `$lists .= "<ul>"` is equivalent to `$lists = ($lists . "<ul>")`.  See http://php.net/language.operators.string for more information.